# Sails.js/waterline self-referenced many to many two way association

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I have the following kind of setup: I have a model called `Person`, which is related to other `Person`s (eg. neighbours) through a many-to-many association. The interpretation is that a person can have many neighbours, and a person can be the neighbour of many other people. The model attributes look just about like this:

```
...
attributes: {
    name: 'string',
    neigh: {
        collection: 'Person',
        via: 'neighOf',
        dominant: true
    },
    neighOf: {
        collection: 'Person',
        via: 'neigh'
    }
}
...
```

Now imagine us having two people, Person A and Person B. A is a neighbor of B, and B is a neighbor of A. A moves away, so they're no longer neighbors. Now when I remove B from the neighs of A, *A will not automatically be removed from the neighs of B*. This is a problem.

I tried to address the problem by creating an `afterUpdate` function to the `Person` model, in which I would check every person in the `neighOf` field of A for whether A still has them as a neighbour, and if not, would update the `Persons` that no longer were neighbours of A. I also wanted to do the opposite, so if A became a neighbour of B again (eg. the `neigh` field of B was updated), the `neigh` field of A should update automatically as well. Here's what I came up with:

```
afterUpdate: function(updatedPerson, cb) {
    Person.findOne(updatedPerson.id)
        .populate('neigh')
        .populate('neighOf')
        .then(function(person) {
            updatedPerson = person;
            var ids = _.pluck(updatedPerson.neigh, 'id');
            return Person.find(ids).populate('neigh');
        })
        .then(function(people) {
            neigh_of_updated = people;
            var ids = _.pluck(updatedPerson.neighOf, 'id');
            return Person.find(ids).populate('neigh');              
        })
        .then(function(people) {
            neighOf_of_updated = people;
            var updates = [];
            _.forEach(neighOf_of_updated, function(person) {
                if (_.find(person.neigh, function(neigh) {return neigh.id === updatedPerson.id})
                    && !_.find(updatedPerson.neigh, function(neigh) {return neigh.id === person.id})) {
                    var neighIds = _.pluck(person.neigh, 'id');
                    _.remove(neighIds, function(id) {
                        return id === updatedPerson.id;
                    });
                    updates.push(Person.update(person.id, {neigh: neighIds}));
                }
            })
            return Promise.all(updates);
        })
        .then(function() {
            var updates = [];
            _.forEach(neighOfUpdated, function(person) {
                if (!_.find(person.neigh, function(neigh) { return neigh.id === updatedPerson.id; })) {
                    var neighIds = _.pluck(person.neigh, 'id');
                    neighIds.push(updatedPerson.id);
                    updates.push(Person.update({id: Person.id}, {neigh: neighIds}))
                }
            })
            return Promise.all(updates);
        })
        .then(function() {
            cb();
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            cb(error);
        })
}
```

So far I haven't been able to get both working. I can get them working separately, but when combined, the code is looping itself endlessly due to some updates happening in the middle of it all, causing new and new afterUpdates to be called.

I feel like this is a pretty common use case, so I'm guessing there should be an easier way to do all of this - or if there isn't, at least some way to get this working. As it is, I feel like I'm hitting my head against a brick wall in a matter that should be an easy task. Anyone have experience of similar associations and how to handle them?